# module.exports client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, module, requirejs

I've created a node module that is essentially just some useful JS that can also be used client side. I know that require.js can load common.js components, but I don't necessarily want to make a mandate that everyone who uses my module client side also needs require or common.js or something. I also don't want to force them to remove the `module.exports = ...` at the bottom of the file. How do others solve this problem? Do you just create 2 versions, or 2 "compiled" versions rather? Does module.exports work everywhere?

Comment: The best exposition on this subject i know of is http://www.2ality.com/2011/11/module-gap.html. The author discusses advantages/disadvantage and development/deployment modes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what underscore.js does:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    exports = module.exports = _;
  }
  exports._ = _;
} else {
  root['_'] = _;
}
```

Comment: I wonder how you can test this part of code to check it is exported successfully.

Answer (score 15):

This answer relies on the fact that assignments are evaluated right to left. `MyModule` is assigned to `exports` first, then `exports` is assigned to `module.exports`.

If `module` is not declared, an exception is thrown.

Short, clean and easy to remember:

```
try {
   module.exports = exports = MyModule;
} catch (e) {}
```

This file can be included in both the browser and node.js.

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me (CoffeeScript). Assume 'Namespace' is what you want to claim on the `window` scope for the client

```
(module ? {}).exports = @Namespace =
  my: 'cool'
  module: '!'
```

Then you can use `require('namespace').my === 'cool'` in Node.js or `Namespace.my === 'cool'` in the browser. This translates into JS as

```
(typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null ? module : {}).exports = this.Namespace = {
  my: 'cool',
  module: '!'
};
```